# Android Database Sugar orm no such table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sugarorm

i'm working on a project in android ! And i use Sugar ORM for the interaction with my database.But i think sugar become crazy sometimes. I have an error No such Column while compiling.I dont understand ! Anywhere in the code I put it.

```
    public List<Plats> getAllplatById(){
        return  Plats.find(Plats.class ,NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("id_menus")+"= ?" ,String.valueOf(id));
    }
```

And i got this error :

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: IDMENUS (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM PLATS WHERE IDMENUS=
```

Please Help me.

Comment: Please update with the full Plats class so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First option is that you should raise the value of your database version in the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data  android:name="VERSION"  android:value="2" />
```

That should be done every time you change something of the classes that you save in your database.

The other option is that you just pick the wrong column name.
I think you should try: "ID_MENUS" as column name and not use the NamingHelper. Because i've seen that kind of names more then IDMENUS ("example).